# html bootstrap - navbar responsive issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to creating a new design for my script, however I've ran into an issue.

The navigation bar looks normal when it's on the regular computer size, but when I run it as a tablet/mobile size, the button goes under the links inside the navigation bar.

http://prntscr.com/61ovfk

So the problem here is only when it's around half the size of the window on a regular computer. When it gets smaller, then it's fine.

Is there a way to fix this?

That's my code,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">companyName</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="order.php">Order Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="announcements.php">Announcements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="knowledgebase.php">Knowledgebase</a></li>
                                <li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li>
                                        <p class="navbar-btn">
                                                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.php">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Manage Account
                                                </a>
                                        </p>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please include all code in the question. This question may become useless in-case link get invalid. Also try using jsfiddle.net Thanks

Comment: there is a crunching point with bootstrap.. they try to take into account all devices.. you might have hit a resolution which is just not comon or hit at all so its not added to the `@media` in the css. You could add your own @media to account for the pixel dimensions and apply styling as required.

Comment: Need to reduce spacing between nav element or button size wherever needed using breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to customize the Bootstrap CSS, or use media queries to override the breakpoint of the navbar.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

http://bootply.com/dwzfF4CeFd

Answer (score 0):

As there are too many menu options in the nav bar while resizing when it hit lower @media break point they get collapsed due limited spacing around it.
Write your appropriate css for lower screen resolution inside below media query break points.

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}
```

I would have fixed it like this; while converting three of the options to **dropdown** to allow my self more spacing on smaller devices. While those three menu options will be hidden on small devices.

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/w74de/8/)**

```
<li class="dropdown visible-sm visible-xs"> <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><a href="knowledgebase.php">Knowledgebase</a>

                </li>
                <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><a href="support.php">Support</a>

                </li>
                <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>

                </li>
```

For more please check **[this](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries)** out.
good luck!